# Biggest possible value to store values over a million with floating points in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, floating-point

I am developing a web app in PHP and MySQL and I am trying to store a value in a row that is bigger than 1 million. Whenever I do an insertion into the database, say if I try to insert 45,234,023.34 (no matter what value) it always gets truncated to 999,999.99. I have chosen an unsigned long for that specific column. I know that that is the max value of that datatype as per the following [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html). Also, I will never have to worry about more than 2 decimals. All my operations will always be 2 decimals no matter what case it is.

Do you guys know how to solve this? What is the correct approach in these situations?

Thank you for your time in advance.

---

Update:

Heres the SQL Code:

```
create table `values` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `desc` text null, `concept` text null, `value` double null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

Please bear in mind that the the column I'm interested in is called "value". Thanks!

Comment: So what is your database column datatype/size?

Comment: Please add the CREATE statement for the table as well as the code that you use to insert these values

Comment: the DECIMAL data type seems exactly what you would want. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Comment: @MarkBaker Added the code!

Comment: @reto added the code!

Comment: @Jakumi thanks for pointing that out. Have you ever used it? Do you know any drawbacks of such datatype in your experience? Is it reliable to execute arithmetic operations? Thanks!

Comment: The default numeric precision for floats is 12, 22 for double; as you haven't specified a precision, then this is what you should get; ie. 22-12 (10) digits maximum before the decimal

Comment: number representation, addition, subtraction are very reliable (better than floats), multiplication/division *may* drop digits, when they exceed the defined precision. it really depends on what those numbers are and what you want to do with them, if the last digits matter a lot and rounding is a problem, you should investigate the corner cases, if they behave as you want.

Comment: What kind of thing does 'value' represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used DECIMAL(12,2). This is because as in the ref [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), this will allow me to have an integer (number to the left of the decimal point) of 10 digits (I only need 9, but I am leaving that extra space in case I decide to use a negative number) and 2 numbers to the right of the decimal point. Tested it throughly in PHP and all operations (ONLY with 2 decimals, anything bigger will be TRUNCATED!) come up right.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `FLOAT(m,n)`, only use `FLOAT`.

`FLOAT` has only 7 digit of precision, so the 10-digit number "45,234,023.34" will lose the last few digits: `45234000`.

Perhaps you want `DOUBLE`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, nobody who doesn't know what they're doing ever needs DOUBLE or FLOAT.

Answer (score 0):

**Your query should be like this:**

```
create table `values` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `desc` text null, `concept` text null, `value` DECIMAL(10,2) null, `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

Ref Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Hope this will help!!